# How can I find null values with SELECT query in psycopg?

Tags: python, null, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 library in python and the `INSERT` query works good when I insert null Value with None, but when I want to do `SELECT` null values, with None doesn't return any.

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil = (%s);", (None,))
```

This query doesnt return any rows, i dont know where is the error.

Anyone know how to make `SELECT` query's to find null values in a DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing to do is find out what query it's turning your command into:

```
print(cur.mogrify("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil = (%s);", (None,)))
```

If that gives you anything other than an `IS NULL` codition check, it won't get NULLs from the table.

Specifically, if you see the phrase `= NULL`, you'll know it's not being translated correctly<sup>(1)</sup> and you'll have to do something like:

```
if var is None:
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NULL;")
else:
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil = (%s);", (var,))
```

Or, if you know you're always looking for `NULL` values (as your use of the constant `None` seems to indicate), just use:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NULL;")
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> It's quite possible that only the `%s` is replaced with a `NULL` when the argument is `None`, and it's not quite clever enough to go back and change `=` into `IS` (or `<>` into `IS NOT`).

This would explain why this works:

```
cur.execute("INSERT into mytbl value (%s);", (None,))
```

(because substitution of *only* the `%s` gives the command you want), but anything with `= NULL` will not act as expected, unless you've been burnt by it enough times to *know* what to expect :-).

Comment: Thanks!!! This works! And if i want to do double condition in where? For example id_movil IS NULL and name = xxx? For example:

Comment: @Telmo, assuming `xxx` isn't None, you can use something like `cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NULL and name = (%s);", ('xxx',))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE (id_movil = (%s) or id_movil is null);", (movil,))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which I'm currently experimenting with is a postgres setting called `transform_null_equals`  (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-TRANSFORM-NULL-EQUALS)

you can set it in `postgresql.conf` or however you do your config (i'm using docker-compose for local dev and RDS for prod, so that means a parameter group).

```
transform_null_equals = 1
```

The effect is that postgres then just magically transforms any `= NULL` queries into `IS NULL` without you having to think about it!

Answer (score 0):

There's a different syntax for checking whether something is `NULL`-valued:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NULL;")
```

The same applies for getting everything that is not `NULL`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NOT NULL;")
```

**EDIT**:

You can combine WHERE clauses using AND just like you normally would:

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT id FROM registro WHERE id_movil IS NULL AND name = (%s);",
    ('Bob',)
)
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works!! And if i want to do double condition in where? For example id_movil IS NULL and name = xxx?